# Search which tables in MySQL have rows with empty ENUMs

Tags: mysql, enums, phpmyadmin

We are cleaning our MySQL database and finding many **rows with empty string (as value) in ENUM columns**. MySQL has the nasty habit of ignoring errors like that, you know.

So, since we have hundreds of tables, I was wondering if there is a way to find **which tables have this problem**. Solutions involving queries, procedures or phpMyAdmin commands are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. My first question here! Yay!

Comment: Do you mean rows with an empty string in an ENUM column, or an empty string as one of the ENUM values?

Comment: You should be able to make a script to use `mysqldump` to dump the schema(e), look for tables with ENUM columns, and then `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM schema.table WHERE table.enumcol = ''` which would even give you a list of how many null entries there are for each field in a table.

Comment: Maybe don't use ENUMs!

Comment: Rows with columns which the value is empty, but without that option in the ENUM definition.

Comment: @Strawberry We are migrating to PostgreSQL. ENUMs are cool guys there.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Well, we don't know which tables/columns have that problems. It is quite tedious to check one by one.

Maybe a procedure that goes to information_schema, loop through the table definitions, loop through their columns, check if it is a ENUM a make a SELECT?

Comment: That's why I suggested a scripted procedural solution to do the checking for you which would spit out a list of all the problem children.  You might not even need to do `mysqldump` if you can use the `root` user; just use `SHOW TABLES` to get a list, `DESCRIBE tablename` to look for `ENUM`, and the aforementioned `SELECT` to check for problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, following the suggestions in the comments, I made a procedure that prints the table name, the column name and the number of rows with empty strings instead of a ENUM value.

It works in mysql terminal app, but not in phpMyAdmin.

```
USE __DATABASE_NAME_HERE__;   

DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS hunt //
CREATE PROCEDURE hunt()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT false;
    DECLARE current_table_name VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE current_column_name VARCHAR(255);

    DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT table_name, column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns
        WHERE information_schema.columns.table_schema = "__DATABASE_NAME_HERE__" AND information_schema.columns.column_type LIKE "%ENUM%";

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN my_cursor;
        my_loop: LOOP
            FETCH my_cursor INTO current_table_name, current_column_name;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE my_loop;
            END IF;

            SET @sql = CONCAT(
                ' SELECT COUNT(*) as column_count, "', current_table_name, '" AS table_name, "', current_column_name, '" AS column_name',
                ' FROM ', current_table_name,
                ' WHERE `', current_column_name , '` = ""',
                ' HAVING column_count > 0'
            );
            PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
            EXECUTE stmt;
            DROP PREPARE stmt;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE my_cursor;

END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL hunt();
```